# Including single-arm studies in a Bayesian network meta-analysis

Tags: bayesian, meta-analysis

I am facing some issues to perform a Bayesian network meta-analysis.

Let us suppose that I have several RCTs comparing either A vs. B, or A vs. C, or B vs. C and that the reference treatment is A.

I understand how to perform pairwise direct and indirect comparisons treatments using a random-effects model in a Bayesian framework. However, I wonder if there is a possibility to also include in the model single-arm studies of B for example?

I have some troubles writing the model to be able to implement it in JAGS.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.